# Does a REPL exist for Bosque?

Tags: bosque

I have checked out the new programming language and i compiled my code examples with **exegen**. In order to get more productive and in order to get faster feedback, i would like to use a REPL.

For example i would like to write this code in the REPL instead of compiling:

```
namespace NSMain;

entrypoint function main(): String {
  return "Hello world";
}
```

I named my file hello-world.bsc and i compile this by getting
`node ./BosqueLanguage/ref_impl/bin/runtimes/exegen/exegen.js hello-world.bsc` getting an `a.out` file, which i am able to execute, which is printing to console:

```
"Hello world"
```

In other languages like Python, Ruby, Clojure, Javascript, etc. i am able to enter the code in a REPL like in this example in Python:

```
>>> print("Hello world")
Hello world
```

Does a REPL exist for **bosque** and how am i able to start it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is none for now. (state February 2023)

Comment: I have taken the liberty to update your answer ;) As of Feb'23 there is still no REPL for Bosque